# Make an image overlap two images in html

Tags: css, html, web

I want to overlap one image over two images at once. It's as if half of the first image was on the upper image and the other half is on the lower.

Any way I can do that?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your layout, you need to use absolute or relative positioning.

Comment: Show us your implementation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry Trix for not responding. Was traveling. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do it like this:

```css
.parent{ position: relative }
.images{ position: absolute; top: 0 }
#img1{ left: 50px; z-index: 10 }
#img2{ left: 0; z-index: 1 }
#img3{ left: 100px; z-index: 1 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="images" id="img1" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/girl-smiley-face-clipart-4ibrqK6ig.jpeg">
  <img class="images" id="img2" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/V/A/J/Z/0/P/smiley-with-three-eyes-th.png">
  <img class="images" id="img3" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/V/A/J/Z/0/P/smiley-with-three-eyes-th.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. I was not adding that position: absolute with the images.

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that this can also be achieved with the help of negative margins.